# subprocess with aws s3 incomplete file copy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, subprocess

I've a process to copy data from mysql to EMR instance and then from EMR to aws s3. The first step has no issues, whereas the copy from EMR to aws s3 is copying partial data (specially the last line is partial in the file).
I'm using the `aws s3 cp` command to copy the data using python

`retval = sub.call(_cmd,shell=True)
if retval != 0:
    print "error"
    sys.exit(1)`

I compare the sizes and see that the size on aws s3 < emr.
If I manually run copy using `aws s3 cp..` is works without any issues.
I'm not sure if `python subprocess` is attributing to this behavior.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `if retval` is sufficient to check for a non zero return status

Comment: Agree. `if retval:` is sufficient to check return status. Any idea on the problem?

Comment: what does the full command look like?

Comment: here is the full command: `aws s3 cp filename.out s3://store-name/tablename/filename.out`

Comment: you receive a 0 exit status?

Comment: yes..unfortunately, i'm getting 0 exit status..and when looked at the end of file, it writes incomplete line of data.

Comment: unrelated: you don't need `shell=True` here: `check_call('aws s3 cp filename.out s3://store-name/tablename/filename.out'.split())`. Your issue seems unrelated to Python.